# Exception for non-exhaustive pattern

Tags: haskell

I tried running this kinda neat/concise `quicksort` implementation in GHCi:

```
:{
qs(x:xs) = qs left ++ [x] ++ qs right
  where left = [ y | y <- xs, y < x]
        right = [ y | y <- xs, y >= x ]
:}
print $ qs [1,123,42,90,24,12,3]
```

The result is :

```
*** Exception: <interactive>:(38,1)-(40,42): Non-exhaustive patterns in function qs
```

What is the relationship of the "where" statement to matcher completeness - and why is it missing cases?

Comment: You might want to add a base case for the empty list: `qs [] = []`.

Comment: @Alec  that did it . please create an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message `Non-exhaustive patterns in function qs` means the pattern matches for `qs` don't cover the full range of inputs `qs` accepts. In this case, you are missing the case for the empty list.

```
:{
qs [] = []
qs (x:xs) = qs left ++ [x] ++ qs right
  where left = [ y | y <- xs, y < x]
        right = [ y | y <- xs, y >= x ]
:}
```

Comment: Worth noting the -Wincomplete-patterns flag, automatically set with -Wall. With that you'd get a warning with both ghc/ghci: `-warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for \`qs': Patterns not matched: []`

Answer (score 3):

As Alec said, you forgot to handle the empty list case.

To avoid this kind of error in the future, I strongly recommend you turn on warnings using `-Wall`. Doing that makes GHC check that patterns are exhaustive at compile-time (definition-time).

```
Prelude> :set -Wall
Prelude> :{
Prelude| qs(x:xs) = qs left ++ [x] ++ qs right
Prelude|   where left = [ y | y <- xs, y < x]
Prelude|         right = [ y | y <- xs, y >= x ]
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:12:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘qs’: Patterns not matched: []
```

As you can see, it points out that `[]` was not matched.

Here's another example, where we handle the empty list and the lists starting by `x,y`, but we forget to handle lists containing one element (pattern of the form `[_]`).

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| f [] = 0
Prelude| f (x:y:xs) = 0
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:18:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘f’: Patterns not matched: [_]
```

Adding `f [x] = 0` would suffice. (Of course, we then get warnings for all the unused variables occurring in these patterns.. :) )

Comment: Thx for the `:set -Wall` tip